# Why is it assigning materials to unselected faces?

Tags: materials

I'm trying to make a 2D face texture; the eye and mouth materials are separate for my convenience. But whenever I try to assign the mouth material to my intended part, it also applies the material to the previous selection even though those faces aren't selected. How do I fix this?
[Video showcasing problem](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10qdP1VbCS0ORZ-DhMzxbRappk2V2zuff/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

In Blender you assign materials to material slots of objects, then assign those material slots to some parts of your model. If you only have one material slot for the object, it will be used for everything instead of only selection, because it's the only one available. Once you have more than one material slot, you can assign different material slots to different parts of your mesh.

[image]

Comment: Oh, there was a video... I hope I guessed what you meant without watching it. :D